# How to maintain context when implementing a new TensorFlow Op?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

When implementing a new TensorFlow Op, if I want to maintain some intermediate data (not necessary a tensor) that is produced and consumed by both the forward and backward functions, how can I do this?

Let's say I need to implement a new layer which requires the storage of an intermediate hashtable for the layer, is there some way to store it in the context of TensorFlow? I don't want to serialize the hashtable as a tensor and need to spend O(n) time to reconstruct the hashtable every time I load it from the TensorFlow context.

Thank you.